# how to use @htmlattributes : for datepicker

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

hello i'm tryinh to change simple input to date form i tried text 
to show a datetime picker with DateTime property 
but when i use 
                `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dateFin, new { type = "date" })`
but it doesn't work 
so i'm using simple input

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateDebut, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control" } })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateFin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

is there someone who's familiar with this form ?

Comment: Are you want to use jQuery datepicker or simply show a datetime picker with `DateTime` property? Please provide model class & explain your goals further to get some insights.

Comment: show a datetime picker with DateTime property . @TetsuyaYamamoto i'm sorry that my post wasn't clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom html helper control for datepicker like

```
public static class HtmlHelper
{  
    public static IHtmlString DatePicker(this HtmlHelper helper, string id)  
  {  
        TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");  
        input .Attributes.Add("type", "date");  
        input .Attributes.Add("id", id);  
        return new MvcHtmlString(input.ToString());  
    }  
}
```

After creating, you need to refer to this class in your razor page with `@using`. And you can use like `@Html.DatePicker("dt1")`